# How do I convert a bash array variable to a string delimited with newlines?

Tags: bash, newlines

I want to write out a bash array variable to a file, with each element on a new line. I could do this with a for loop, but is there another (cleaner) way to join the elements with `\n`?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Here's a way that utilizes bash parameter expansion and its `IFS` special variable.

```
$ System=('s1' 's2' 's3' 's4 4 4')
$ ( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${System[*]}" )
```

We use a subshell to avoid overwriting the value of `IFS` in the current environment. In that subshell, we then modify the value of `IFS` so that the first character is a newline (using `$'...'` quoting). Finally, we use parameter expansion to print the contents of the array as a single word; each element is separated by the first charater of `IFS`.

To capture to a variable:

```
$ var=$( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${System[*]}" )
```

If your bash is new enough (4.2 or later), you can (and should) still use `printf` with the `-v` option:

```
$ printf -v var "%s\n" "${System[@]}"
```

In either case, you may not want the final newline in `var`. To remove it:

```
$ var=${var%?}    # Remove the final character of var
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to output this to a variable?

Comment: Updated to show how to capture to a variable.

Comment: Shouldn't the last example be `var=${var%?}` instead? This is not a regular expression, so `.` will match only a period character.

Comment: Need quotes the array variable name:
```$ IFS=', '
$ echo ${VAR[*]}
first second third

$ echo "${VAR[*]}"
first,second,third```

Comment: `var=$( .. )` trims the trailing newline automatically; `printf -v var` doesn't

Answer (score 36):

You can use `printf` to print each array item on its own line:

```
 $ System=('s1' 's2' 's3' 's4 4 4')
 $ printf "%s\n"  "${System[@]}"
s1
s2
s3
s4 4 4
```

Answer (score 11):

```
awk -v sep='\n' 'BEGIN{ORS=OFS="";for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++){print ARGV[i],ARGC-i-1?sep:""}}' "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
perl -le 'print join "\n",@ARGV' "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
python -c 'import sys;print "\n".join(sys.argv[1:])' "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
sh -c 'IFS=$'\''\n'\'';echo "$*"' '' "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
lua <(echo 'print(table.concat(arg,"\n"))') "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
tclsh <(echo 'puts [join $argv "\n"]') "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
php -r 'echo implode("\n",array_slice($argv,1));' -- "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
ruby -e 'puts ARGV.join("\n")' "${arr[@]}"
```

that's all I can remind so far.

Answer (score 2):

Above solutions are pretty much it, but the original question asks for output to file:

```
$ a=(a b c d e)
$ ( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${a[*]}" ) > /tmp/file
$ cat /tmp/file
a
b
c
d
e
$
```

Notes:
1) 'echo' provides the final newline
2) If this file will just be read in by bash again, then declare -p may be the serialization wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Using *for*:

```
for each in "${alpha[@]}"
do
  echo "$each"
done
```

Using *history*; note this will fail if your values contain `!`:

```
history -p "${alpha[@]}"
```

Using *basename*; note this will fail if your values contain `/`:

```
basename -a "${alpha[@]}"
```

Using *shuf*; note that results might not come out in order:

```
shuf -e "${alpha[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

[My take](https://github.com/jcayzac/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile#L21-L31), using only Bash builtins, without mutating `IFS`:

```bsh
# $1  separator
# $2… strings
join_strings () {
    declare separator="$1";
    declare -a args=("${@:2}");
    declare result;
    printf -v result '%s' "${args[@]/#/$separator}";
    printf '%s' "${result:${#separator}}"
}
```

#### Example

```bsh
$ join_strings $'\n' "a b c" "d e f" "g h i"
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

You can also use any separator:

```bsh
$ join_strings '===' "a b c" "d e f" "g h i"
a b c===d e f===g h i
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my impression of joinArray:

```
function joinArray() {
  local delimiter="${1}"
  local output="${2}"
  for param in ${@:3}; do
    output="${output}${delimiter}${param}"
  done

  echo "${output}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` seems to be the most efficient approach for creating a delimited string from an array:

```
# create a delimited string; note that printf doesn't put the trailing delimiter
# need to save and restore IFS
# it is prudent to put the whole logic on a single line so as to minimize the risk of future code changes breaking the sequence of saving/restoring of IFS
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; printf -v var "${arr[*]}"; IFS=$oldIFS

# print string to file; note that the newline is required in the format string because printf wouldn't put a trailing delimiter (which is a good thing)
printf '%s\n' "$var" > file
```

An even simpler way to do this is:

```
delim=$'\n'
printf -v var "%s$delim" "${arr[@]}" # create a delimited string
var="${var%$delim}"                  # remove the trailing delimiter
```

---

## Example

```
delim=:
arr=(one two three)
printf -v var "%s$delim" "${arr[@]}" # yields one:two:three:
var="${var%$delim}"                  # yields one:two_three
```

Comment: Downvoter, please comment what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the following:

```
$ printf -v var "%s\n" "${System[@]}"
```

works, if you're converting to a string, but you have to deal with the single blank line at the end. I find you can avoid this by using command substitution instead, so

```
$ var=$(printf '%\n' "${System[@]}")
```

should work just fine. Just remember to quote var to get the required effect!