# convert a bash array variable to a string delimited with `.`?

Tags: linux, bash, git

Not a duplicate of [question](https://superuser.com/questions/461981/how-do-i-convert-a-bash-array-variable-to-a-string-delimited-with-newlines).

I am trying to make semvar pattern (1.0.0) from array having 1,0,0 as elements and create a git tag `git tag $var`.

Error:- The above solution is just not working for `.` only, it is giving `1 0 0`, space separated.

```
4 13 0
fatal: too many params
```

Error with git tag command.

Approach:-

```
var=$( IFS=$'.'; echo "${versionArray[*]}" )
echo $var
git tag $var
```

Please suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: What is the exact input and exact output required?

Comment: What is `$IFS` in your main shell? If it's `.` then `echo $var` will print `1 0 0`; but `echo "$var"` should print `1.0.0`. Note for the same reason `echo $IFS` is not a right way to print `$IFS`.

Comment: Also, just `IFS=.` should be enough to set the value. `.` has no special meaning under the ANSI C escaping rules.

Comment: `$IFS` is not printing anything. @KamilMaciorowski .

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `echo "$var"` worked for me. Please put it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the shell that executes `echo $var` and `git tag $var` uses `IFS=.` as well. Note `var=$(IFS=.;…)` cannot change the variable value in the current shell, so this unexpected `IFS` must have been set earlier, probably during some trials and errors.

If I'm right, the variable named `var` holds the expected value with dots, e.g. `1.0.0`. But when you retrieve it like this

```
echo $var
```

the current `IFS` is used to split `1.0.0` into words, so `echo` receives three separate arguments: `1`, `0`, `0`. And because `echo` prints its arguments with single spaces in between, you were under impression the value of `var` was `1 0 0`.

This line

```
echo "$var"
```

doesn't rely on `IFS`. I expect it will show you `1.0.0`.

---

A general solution is to double-quote variables. You [should have done it anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618):

```
echo "$var"
git tag "$var"
```

Also pay attention to `IFS`. Now it should be clear `echo $IFS` won't show you what the variable is; `echo "$IFS"` is better. In addition these methods are useful:

```
printf '%s' "$IFS" | hexdump -c
printf '%s' "$IFS" | hexdump -C
printf '%s' "$IFS" | xxd
```

Comment: Very well.
Yes, he variable named `var` holds the expected value with dots, I am able to write in another file properly.
Thanks for the time and efforts.

Comment: I'd also recommend against leaving nonstandard values of `IFS` active any more than necessary, since (as we're seeing) it can have unexpected effects. `var=$(IFS=.;…)` is fine, since the change is isolated to a subshell performing one operation. In other cases, when you need to change it, it's best to make the change, do what you need the nonstandard value for, and then *immediately* set it back to normal.